# How to find div element by text with python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have to find this text and select.
[image]

I tried :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="product-detail-app"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]').text
print(element)
```

But it gives error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11408/4199675862.py in <module>
      9 search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
     10 result = driver.find_element_by_class_name("prdct-desc-cntnr-name").click()
---> 11 price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="product-detail-app"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]')
     12 print(element)
     13 #for i in browser.find_elements_by_class_name("sp-itm"):

c:\users\seher\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath)
    392             element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/td[1]')
    393         """
--> 394         return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
    395 
    396     def find_elements_by_xpath(self, xpath):

c:\users\seher\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    977             'using': by,
--> 978             'value': value})['value']
    979 
    980     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

c:\users\seher\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

c:\users\seher\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="product-detail-app"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]"}
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.71)
```

I tried different solutions but they didn't work. This is a selectable `div`. I have to find the text I need and set it selectable. But I can't find the text. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Can you share the link to that page?

Comment: @Prophet Of course;
https://www.trendyol.com/trendyolmilla/siyah-volanli-elbise-twoaw20el1313-p-43538005?boutiqueId=584308&merchantId=968

I have to choose the number '38' from the size chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a wait before accessing the element, something like this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)


value = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="product-detail-app"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]'))).text
print(value)
```

Also your XPath locator looks very bad. In can be highly unreliable.
**UPD**
The better XPath locator for that element can be `//div[@class='variants']//div[text()='38']` so your code will be:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)


value = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='variants']//div[text()='38']"))).text
print(value)
```

**UPD**
Seems you have to switch to the new window.
Try this:

```py
new_window = driver.window_handles[-1]
driver.switch_to_window(new_window)
```

To get back to the first window you will have to do this:

```py
old_window = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to_window(old_window)
```

Comment: I tried this solution before, it didn't give an error but no output either. I tried again and the result didn't change.

Comment: What about the updated version?

Comment: I know this solution too but it doesn't work. It gives TimeoutException Error

Comment: Do you maximize the screen / set it to big enough size at the beginning of the session?

Comment: Yes, when I run the code I maximize the screen as soon as Chrome opens.

Comment: And you can access other elements on that page normally?

Comment: This page is the third tab I want to event click. I'm working fine in previous tabs, but I can't work here. So unfortunately no.

Comment: Now I understand (I hope).

Comment: What is problem and solution ? :(

Comment: See the updated answer